# Grid not expanding to fill screen

Tags: android, xamarin, android-gridview, xamarin.forms

I have the following grid, which is loaded inside a StackLayout:

```
            Grid grid = new Grid {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowDefinitions = 
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            },
            ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            }
        };

        grid.Children.Add (btnMenu, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add (lblProfile, 1, 5, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add (btnEdit, 4, 5, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add (lblFirstName, 1, 2, 1, 2);
        grid.Children.Add (lblFirstNameValue, 2, 3, 1, 2);

        Content = new StackLayout { 
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children = { 
                grid
            }
        };
```

I have changed the width values and types of the width of the grid, but I can't make it to fill the whole screen, unless I use fixed values, which will look fine on my phone but really bad on everything else.

Comment: Try adding `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand`to the parent `StackLayout`

Comment: HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand worked, thanks!

Comment: Cool glad it worked, I posted it as an answer as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` to the parent `StackLayout`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add the `VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand` to the parent `StackLayout` as well as set the grandparent `Frame` to `Padding = 0`